# How to write to a text file using Fable?

Tags: .net, f#, file-writing, fable-f#

I'm trying to use Fable to convert some f# code I wrote into a web project, but I'm having some trouble with writing file output. Previously, when I just had a net core project, I could just do something like this:

```
File.WriteAllText("output.txt", "hello")
```

But now if I try that, I get this error:

```
error FABLE: Cannot resolve System.IO.File.WriteAllText @ ./src/App.fsproj
```

Is there something I need to import/add to make this work? Or is there a different way to write files in Fable? I would really appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are running on node.js you should be able to do this - but the official library [fable-node] (https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-node) does not yet seem to support file system operations yet.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you cannot write to file from JavaScript and therefore you cannot write to file from Fable. It all might look confusing in the beginning, but maybe one good rule of thumb is that you cannot use *most of* the `System` namespace stuff directly in Fable.

However the good news is that a bunch of things is available (e.g. `System.Console.WriteLine`) and a bigger bunch is somehow mapped to something in Fable (e.g. `System.Math`, `System.Collections`). You can read more [here](https://fable.io/fable-doc/dotnet/compatibility.html).

Answer (score 1):

*Fable* compiles to *Javascript* that executes in the client side e.g. in your browser (from which you do not have file access).

To write a file you do it on the server side e.g. create a server side API with *Giraffe* or *Suave* or any framework you prefer.   Implement the file writing in this API.

```
open Giraffe.HttpHandlers
open Giraffe.Middleware

let webApp =
    choose [
        route "/api"   >=> File.WriteAllText("output.txt", "hello")
                           setStatusCode 200 
 ]
```

Call your API from *Fable* using for example using a post call.

```
   open Fable.Import.Fetch
   open Fable.Helpers.Fetch

    sync { 
        do! 
          postRecord(API, ...

    }
```

Comment: Fable transpiles to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Fable F# in Node.js:

```ml
open Node.Api

fs.writeFileSync("output.txt", "hello")
```